# get wallet skey/vkey from mnemonic

Tags: cardano-cli, address, cardano-address

I am trying to get the skey, vkey and address of the first payment address in a wallet I created in cardano-wallet. I need them because I would like to make transactions with cardano-cli on the same wallet. I am working on the testnet.

With cardano-wallet I created the wallet using

```
cardano-wallet wallet create from-recovery-phrase "test"
```

I entered my mnemonic phrase, let the second factor empty and set a passphrase.
Everything seems fine and I can have a list of addresses

```
   {
        "derivation_path": [
            "1852H",
            "1815H",
            "0H",
            "0",
            "0"
        ],
        "id": "addr_test1qzwk908vw9lkpvuth4ch9xlmqxk593xtg7060ve775ja300ur5hrj7gda3wde08v8wx9k8dnf0n9ng0hh4ktmr3hjhts7yurnm",
        "state": "used"
    },
...
```

So the first address is *addr_test1qzwk908vw9lkpvuth4ch9xlmqxk593xtg7060ve775ja300ur5hrj7gda3wde08v8wx9k8dnf0n9ng0hh4ktmr3hjhts7yurnm*

I thought I could find the same address by doing:

```
cardano-wallet key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > test.xsk
cat test.xsk | cardano-wallet key child 1852H/1815H/0H/0/0 > test.prv
cat test.prv | cardano-wallet key public --with-chain-code > test.pub
cat test.pub | cardano-address address payment --network-tag testnet > test.addr
```

But I got this address:
*addr_test1vzwk908vw9lkpvuth4ch9xlmqxk593xtg7060ve775ja30gg6szrd*

I tried with cardano-address I got the same address.

I also try this with cardano-cli:

```
cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --shelley-payment-key --signing-key-file test.prv --out-file test.skey
cardano-cli key verification-key --signing-key-file keys/test1.skey --verification-key-file test.vkey
cardano-cli address build --payment-verification-key-file test.vkey --out-file test.addr --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

And I also got *addr_test1vzwk908vw9lkpvuth4ch9xlmqxk593xtg7060ve775ja30gg6szrd*

When I tried to make a transaction from my wallet to this address, it's seems to be a valid derivative address because all utxo appears when I am checking with

```
cardano-wallet wallet utxo-snapshot
```

But I don't understand why I don't have the same address with the same derivative path.
I also checked with yoroi and nami wallet and *addr_test1qzwk908vw9lkpvuth4ch9xlmqxk593xtg7060ve775ja300ur5hrj7gda3wde08v8wx9k8dnf0n9ng0hh4ktmr3hjhts7yurnm* is the usual address for them

Can someone tell me what I am missing ?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the stake key.
You obtain the stake key pair like this:

```
cat rootkey.prv | cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/2/0 > stake.prv
cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --signing-key-file stake.prv --shelley-stake-key --out-file stake.skey
cardano-cli key verification-key --signing-key-file stake.skey --verification-key-file Ext_ShelleyStake.vkey
cardano-cli key non-extended-key --extended-verification-key-file Ext_ShelleyStake.vkey --verification-key-file stake.vkey
```

And then you can build your address with the stake included (from the keys obtained with the cardano-cli version you posted):

```
cardano-cli address build --payment-verification-key-file test.vkey --stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey --out-file test.addr --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

And you use the same stake key pair for all addresses derived from the master key.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I was missing !